# stellar-core process is killed with stellar-core: bucket/FutureBucket.cpp:114: void

Tags: stellar-core

I am now setting up stellar-core in my amazon cloud services.

I have tried to run with "./stellar-core &"

however, it is showing the below messages on the phase of "Catching up: applying checkpoint"

Is there someone to resolve the problem ?

2018-03-17T21:57:57.396 GBZ4X [History INFO] Catching up: applying checkpoint 1378/235940 (0%)
stellar-core: bucket/FutureBucket.cpp:114: void stellar::FutureBucket::checkState() const: Assertion `mInputSnapBucket' failed.

2018-03-19T20:05:02.539 GBZ4X [History INFO] Catching up: applying checkpoint 5625/235037 (2%)
stellar-core: bucket/FutureBucket.cpp:114: void stellar::FutureBucket::checkState() const: Assertion `mInputSnapBucket' failed.

Comment: This looks like a bug in stellar-core. Could you create an issue here: https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/issues ?